# Installing Python 3.6: question about needing sudo command for configure command

Tags: pi-3, software-installation, python-3, sudo

I have a Raspberry pi 3 Model B and I want to install Python 3.6 on it.

A bit of context:

- I acquired this Raspberry pi over 2 years ago and it came with Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed by default in /usr/bin/.
- To install Python 3.6, I used the following instructions:

https://installvirtual.com/install-python-3-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/

Briefly, the commands in that link are:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev

$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8.tgz

$ sudo tar zxf Python-3.6.8.tgz
$ cd Python-3.6.8
$ ./configure
$ make -j 4
$ make altinstall
```

I tried following theses instructions but:

1) I made a directory in my home into which I downloaded the .tgz file. In other words, before the wget command, I did:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir my-packages/my-python3.6 && cd /my-packages/my-python3.6
```

I don't think this changes anything but in any case, I thought I should say it.

2) All was well but when doing the ./configure command and the following 2, I was shown a permission denied. Unfortunately I don't have the exact error messages for all 3 commands (the output was so big I can't go back) but I do have it for the "make -j 4" command:

```
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create Parser/grammar1.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1589: recipe for target 'Parser/grammar1.o' failed
make: *** [Parser/grammar1.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create Programs/python.o: Permission denied
Makefile:766: recipe for target 'Programs/python.o' failed
make: *** [Programs/python.o] Error 1
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create Parser/acceler.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1589: recipe for target 'Parser/acceler.o' failed
make: *** [Parser/acceler.o] Error 1
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create Parser/listnode.o: Permission denied
Makefile:1589: recipe for target 'Parser/listnode.o' failed
make: *** [Parser/listnode.o] Error 1
```

When I used "sudo" in front of all 3 commands, it seems to work.

**So my question is:**
Why did I need to use sudo for all 3 commands? I have not found any tutorial saying this. Maybe I'm overthinking this but I find it weird to have needed sudo when no else seemed to. Could I have done something wrong?

Also, is it common for a Python installed from source to go to /usr/local/bin?

My sudo rights are:

```
$ sudo -l

# Output:
Matching Defaults entries for pi on raspberrypi:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User pi may run the following commands on raspberrypi:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just download a recent Raspbian?  That comes with Python 3.7.3. Presumably you need root permission to write to the directories showing an error.  Since you haven't told us where those directories are it's a bit pointless commenting further.

Comment: I guess so, but I was hoping to just download 3.6 rather than spend time upgrading my OS. To answer your second point, Python 3.6 was installed in /usr/local/bin. I am just confused as to why I needed sudo rights to write to there.

Comment: Each distribution will have its own rules about where to put various classes of software.  Debian/Raspbian chooses /usr/local/bin for user installed software which is to be accesisble to all users.  /usr is owned by root.  /usr/local is owned by root. /usr/local/bin is owned by root.  So you need root permissions.

Comment: Ok so I guess its all ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your permissions/folder question: you need `root` permissions for `/usr/local/bin` because that folder belongs to `root`, and the reason for that is that the `root` user has that directory in their `$PATH`.

If `/usr/local/bin` was write-accessible to anyone, a malicious user could create a script there named as a common typo, such as `cd..`, or a common command which is not installed on your system, e.g. `lynx` or `convert`. After that, making the expected typo or trying to run the expected command (e.g. double-clicking an HTML/JPEG file in some file managers) while running as `root` would execute the script, effectively elevating the malicious user's permissions.

If you want to install software for the `pi` user only, create a folder `/home/pi/bin`, add it to your `$PATH` and install your software there. Obviously, this doesn't require `root` permissions, since there's no risk that `root` or any other user will accidentally run that software.

And yes, it is absolutely common for software installed from sources to go into `/usr/local/bin`. You should never install anything in `/usr/bin` without using your package manager (`apt`).

Answer (score 2):

You can install Python3.7 with `sudo apt-get install python3.7`. It's more easier to install it.

Comment: That only works on Buster. The OP hasn't upgraded to Buster.